# PapaParse putting one-word column name in quotes

Tags: papaparse

I have a csv file and that's how PapaParse is rendering it:

```js
{
    'user': '...',
    answer: '',
    '1 msg': '',
    '2 msg': '',
    ads: '200',
    '': '',
    _1: '',
    _2: ''
  }
```

PapaParse function:

```js
function toJson () {
  const file = fs.createReadStream('./olx-sellers.csv')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      complete (results, file) {
        resolve(results.data)
      },
      error (err, file) {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I don't know why `user` is in quotes and `answer` is not. How can I change it? I would understand if it's two-word name, but as a one-word it kinda doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you provide more info, e.g,. your code, or at least what functions have you used -- I don't see any PapaParse function that displays something like your output, it typically returns a [parse result object](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#results).

Comment: How does the csv file look (maybe you can add a few lines including the first/header line to your question)? It could be that there is something going on with the column names in the csv file.

Comment: Well, the problem doesn't seem to be caused by papaparse, nor by the code you included. Papaparse's `results.data` is a javascript object, so the problem is with how you format that object to output afterwards, which happens in `resolve`. If you do `toJson().then(data=>console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)))` you'll get full json formatting. For a leaner output you may consider using node's [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors) or a Json5 library.

Comment: The missing piece. Thank you, @kikon